# RabbitMQ Set the HA Policy

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I know the HA Policy is set by the following command:

```
$ rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

My question which seems basic:

Do I have to issue this command on each node or just one of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RabbitMQ provides to distributes the policy to all the cluster, so it does not matter which node you select the info will be distribute to the other nodes.

Please read here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

> A RabbitMQ broker is a logical grouping of one or several Erlang
>   nodes, each running the RabbitMQ application and sharing users,
>   virtual hosts, queues, exchanges, bindings, and runtime parameters.
>   Sometimes we refer to the collection of nodes as a cluster.